# ReSharper don't see Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I use Visual C# 2010 and I wanna install ReSharper over it but I can't becouse ReSharper installer didn't see VS installed on my computer
http://scr.hu/76jw/af8el
How can I deal with it?

Comment: resharper understands location of VS from windows registery. so you probably didnt install VS correctly or didnt installed correct original version.[Visual studio 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23507). there are also many other possibilities. Try Reinstalling it.

Comment: Any chance you're using the Express edition? Because Express editions can't support plugins.

Comment: sorry for lat answer, yes I used express edition, thanks for that information

Answer (score 0):

Try **Repairing** Visual Studio. You can do this through Visual Studio Installer or by going at Control Panel/Programs And Features, selecting Visual Studio and then pressing **Change**.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting **Visual Studio**

> `Devenv /ResetSettings SettingsFile`

If it doesn't work you should consider reinstalling Visual Studio